# How to enable git autocomplete in integrated terminal in VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm using VS Code on Mac.
I frequently use integrated terminal in VS Code for performing command line operations relevant to my workspace/project [instead of using Terminal or iTerm].

I am able to use autocomplete for basic shell commands via Integrated terminal in VS Code.
For example doing `cd`  followed by a `Tab` automatically suggests possible directory options for me [just like Terminal or iTerm would].

However, this automatic suggestion doesn't work for git commands.
For example, doing `git br` followed by a `Tab` should complete to `git branch` but that's not working.

I looked at User Settings in VS Code [by invoking `Cmd + Shift + P` -> User Settings -> User -> Extensions -> Git
I verified my default terminal for Mac is "Terminal". But however, it's not picking Git commands for autocomplete.

What's missing?

Related issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17748

Comment: For Bash, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399002/how-to-configure-git-bash-command-line-completion

Answer (score 11):

If you're using zsh shell, there is a good and quick solution for it right in this discussion.
[Git tab completion not working in zsh on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58517668/7578070)

Then in VSCode, choose zsh as your default terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issues with VSCode and Windows 10. The default terminal was set to Powershell. After i installed poshgit https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git autocompletion works fine.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me slightly. I didn't install `posh-git.` Instead, instead of clicking the plus icon to open a new terminal, I clicked the arrow next to the plus icon and selected `Git bash`. So it opened `Git bash` instead of `Powershell` and autocomplete was working.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your .zshrc: `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit`

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following commands:

```
// switch to root folder
cd ~

// check for .bashrc file, it is most likely a hidden file
ls -A -l

// enable git auto-complete by uncommenting the lines that enable it.
// At the time of writing, these are the last 3 lines in the file.
// The lines look like this after uncommenting.

if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

This solved the problem for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using zsh, you can configure vscode terminal by default with zsh terminal. Go to `preferences` -> `Settings` and click on the top right icon to open the json view. Then add the following settings

```json
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh"
```

This assumes you already have git autocomplete in your zsh terminal but not within vscode. If you don't have git autocomplete in your terminal, I'd suggest using [Oh my zsh](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh) which already has nice plugins for git and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MacOS,you could use Fig.
I use it myself and it has great autocomplete, in VSCode's integrated terminal as well!

[fig.io](https://fig.io/)