# Trying to autocomplete `git stash drop` produces error output

Tags: git, ubuntu

Whenever I press tab after entering `git stash drop`, I get the following error message (outputted thrice in a row):

```
_arguments:comparguments:325: invalid argument: _git-notes
_git-stash:88: command not found: (-q --quiet)-q[suppress all output]
```

The actual stash deletion still *does* work, but it's a hassle to have to list my stashes first before choosing.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling git, but to no avail.

If it helps, I upgraded recently to Ubuntu 20.04 from 19.10 and I don't recall this bug ever appearing in the previous OS version.

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between the autocomplete script for your Git, your Git itself, and/or your version of bash. Installing a new Git doesn't always update the autocompletion scripts. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14970728/1256452) is for OSX, not Ubuntu, but is worth seeing.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @SergioLeone I googled git autocompletion and came upon [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@oliverspryn/adding-git-completion-to-zsh-60f3b0e7ffbc) for adding autocompletion to zsh, the shell I use. While it does fix the error, whenever I press tab after `git stash drop stash@{`, it only adds another curly brace, which results to `git stash drop stash@{{`.

Comment: Doesn't look like a solution to me. The rest of the autocomplete functions work fine, only `git stash drop` is the problematic one (And actaully I've also started experiencing this on Ubuntu 20.04) I've opened an issue with omzsh for this, let's see what they say.

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: Yes, the [issue](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/8956) was closed because it is not a problem of ohmyzsh.

Comment: It seems that has been fixed by zsh-5.8-44-g754658aff (according to https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00915.html)

Answer (score 3):

I found a temporary solution (until Ubuntu gets a later version of zsh with the fix) here:

https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/9264

This github issue references the zsh commit which fixes it: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/754658aff38e1bdf487c58bec6174cbecd019d11

**So - taken from those places you can do this to fix it:**

1. Run this to find the file you need to edit: `ls -l ${^fpath}/_git(N)`
2. Edit the file, for me it was: `vim /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git`

   - On line  1812

     - Change from `_arguments -S $endopt \_git-notes` to `_arguments -S $endopt \`
3. Close and reopen your zsh terminal.

The `gstd` command should now work fine without receiving errors. I did this a few months ago and it's been fine ever since. Had to do it on another machine which is why I ended up looking for this solution again. Thought I'd post here to help myself (and everyone else) for the future!

Comment: On macOS you have to copy `/usr/share/zsh/5.8/functions/_git` to `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` before changing it as /usr/share is protected.